# Android xamarin app not working after some days

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm in trouble with app installed in a device android and developed with xamarin. After developing and testing in debug mode, I deployed the app in Release to a device.
After few days and with no updating of the app or variations, the app does not start anymore. Tapping on the app it opens for a few second and close. The same app that works perfectly yesterday.
And this happens with all apps developed with xamarin.
What can be? Any idea?
I'm using visual studio 2015.
There is a log to check?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad to be posted here, but take a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/ for some help finding logs with more information

Comment: Are you sure that you've published app correctly? What steps did you do to produce APK?

Comment: After debug session with the device or emulator, I set release and so Deploy Solution from BUild Menu. Maybe the proble caused by Any CPU settings?

Comment: After a search I read the log with adb logcat and activating the app I can see this error: 
    09-21 09:02:23.018 W/monodroid(16964): JNIEnv.FindClass(Type) caught unexpected exception: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.UncaughtExceptionHandler" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/PRBNetworkMonitor.Droid-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/MyNetworkMonitor.Droid-1/lib/arm, /data/app/MyNetworkMonitor.Droid-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Why this library disappear??